# I want to avoid Mouse click event handled by both child and parent handlers in javafx 8

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

Currently in my javafx program I have structure like

AnchorPane[Parent] - > Group[Child] ... Both have setOnMouseClicked event code..

My problem is When click on child node, child node's setOnMouseClicked executed first and then Parent node's setOnMouseClicked  gets executed ...

Now I have situation where I want to have functionality like

- If child node's setOnMouseClicked is executed then
- Parent node's setOnMouseClicked should not get executed ..

How do I achieve this ? For more information please check below image.

[image]

1. Now if I click on parent node - > selected child node should be deselected .. So I write parent Node.setOnMouseClicked -> de-select child node ..
2. But even when I click on child node to select it - > it also execute parent node's setOnMouseClicked - > And immediately deselect the child node ..

I find this problem as an architectural issue so as not posting code example.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at event filters and consuming events - [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm) should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small example of consuming events - events that have been consumed will not bubble through to the next listeners:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Canvas c = new Canvas(400, 400);
    Pane p = new Pane(c);
    p.setOnMouseClicked(me -> {
        System.out.println("Pane mouse click: " + me.getX() + ", " + me.getY());
    });
    c.setOnMouseClicked(me -> {
        System.out.println("Canvas mouse click: " + me.getX() + ", " + me.getY());
        if (me.getX()>200) {
            System.out.println("Consuming event");
            me.consume();
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(new Scene(p));
    stage.show();
}
```

When clicking the left part and then the right part of the `Canvas` you will get something like this:

```
Canvas mouse click: 96.0, 174.0
Pane mouse click: 96.0, 174.0
Canvas mouse click: 373.0, 180.0
Consuming event
```

Notice how the second time the `Pane` event listener wasn't executed. Of course, you can use any logic to decide whether you consume the event.